# Sklearn - Choosing the right model for supervised learning/classification task

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am beginning to learn how to use `scikit-learn` and I have a hard time choosing the right model.

Here is my dataset:
I have 100 persons.
Each person was measured three times: baseline, first event and second event.
Each measurement had 100 different markers per person that range from 0.1 to 1000.
Additionally I have outcome measurements of each event: outcome can be 0, 1 or 2.
My task is to find just a few markers (let’s say 10) that can predict outcome.
If I am right it should be: Supervised learning/Classification problem.
What model would be the best?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot say beforehand what the best model is. This also depends on the goal you want to achieve. Are you only interested in accuracy? Do you prefer to have few false positives? And the list goes on and on. However, classification, seems to be suitable here.

Comment: Ups, sorry. Did not know that there is the site ".Cross Validated". My apologies

Comment: Please do not cross post. That is against SE policy for just this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will be a Supervised/Classification problem.100 different markers per person become your features input to the model.You can analyze which markers(features) are having a higher correlation to the response(outcome) variable in each case using correlation techniques.You can also use dimensionality reduction techniques such as PCA (Principal Component Analysis) to narrow down your features.Using linear classifier algorithm (Logistic Regression,LDA etc) on the resultant features(markers) should suffice and give you good classification accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

LDA(LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) is a Supervised learning decomposition algorithm.
this algorithm is included in sklearn package.
you can use it

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
```

`lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)`

```
lda.fit(X,y)

X_new = lda.transform(X)
```